# How to get a gnu screen session to auto start with a specific command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, automation, gnu-screen

I need a certain program to run inside a gnu screen session, automatically when an ubuntu machine boots.

How can I set it up so that later on I can just `screen -r` and interact with the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
screen -d -m command
```

Quoting the documentation:

> Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but
>   doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

But keep in mind that once the command finishes, the screen terminates as well.

Comment: i would use this, then call the shell, and pass a command to the shell and tell it not to terminate

Comment: if the screen terminates when the command finishes, it doesn't solve my problem. how would i get to not terminate?

Comment: @GJ. Do you need to "interact with the program" or inspect its output? You can not interact with a program after it finishes.

Comment: I need to interact with it while it's running, and inspect its output after it finishes

Comment: @GJ. So create a script that calls the command and then waits for Enter (`read`). Call this script from `screen -d -m`.

Comment: good idea @choroba